# Полный список расширений PostgreSQL относительно ISO/IEC SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, стандарт

Читая документацию к *PostgreSQL* часто встречаю [подобные](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-character.html)
части (выделение добавлено):

> The notations `varchar(n)` and `char(n)` are aliases
> for `character varying(n)` and `character(n)`,
> respectively.  `character` without length specifier is equivalent to
> `character(1)`.  If `character varying` is used without
> length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size.  **The latter is
> a PostgreSQL extension.**

Есть ли в самой документации или где-то в интернете
список всех расширений и прочих отличий *SQL*, понимаемого
*PostgreSQL*, от стандартного *SQL*
из *ISO/IEC 9075*?

---

Нашёл [вот этот раздел](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/features.html),
где описывается, *какие* фичи поддерживаются,
но не описаны детали, расширения, синонимы,
и тому подобное.

Comment: `от стандартного SQL из ISO/IEC 9075` - обратите внимание, что это уже 9 различающихся стандартов, при том каждый из них состоит из core части и набора независимых дополнений. Ну и отдельную боль разработчиков СУБД "а этот стандарт хоть когда-то был однозначным?" - разные реализации стандарта могут себя вести по-разному не только потому что так решили, но и потому что поняли эту часть по-разному. А потому на вопрос вовсе невозможно ответить, это будет лишь ещё одна интерпретация не до конца конкретного текста стандарта.

Comment: Про то, что стандарт «слегка нестандартный», я знаю.  Меня прежде всего интересует список того, как *PostgreSQL* его расширяет и, там где в стандарте неясность, как он её интерпретирует.  Про конкретные части стандарта я уже нашёл раздел и добавил его в вопрос.

Comment: Мне просто непонятно зачем такой список нужен. Усилий требует много, так же на дальнейшее поддержание списка (тот самый раздел `D.1. Supported Features` несколько раз обновлять забывали точно). Что есть и как реализовано - почти весь мануал и есть об этом